# Datanucleus - DBCP2 integration warning - PoolableConnectionFactory not linked to pool

Tags: java, gwt, jdo, datanucleus, apache-commons-dbcp

I want to upgrade a GWT-JDO application to use DBCP2 instead of DBCP. The configuration part works pretty well, but I see a warning in the console

```
WARN [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource] PoolableConnectionFactory not linked to pool. Calling setPool() to fix the configuration.
```

The PersistenceManagerFactory is build using JDOHelper, so I haven't access to the DBCP2 object in order to set the pool. We are using

```
JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(properties)
```

I performed some debugging in the JDO classes and I found that even if the warning is raised, the pool is actually set to the connection factory.
Please find bellow the code from org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource

```
// Verify that _pool's factory refers back to it.  If not, log a warning and try to fix.
        if (pcf.getPool() != _pool) {
            log.warn(Utils.getMessage("poolingDataSource.factoryConfig"));
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // PCF must have a pool of PCs
            ObjectPool<PoolableConnection> p = (ObjectPool<PoolableConnection>) _pool;
            pcf.setPool(p);
        }
```

Do someone know a way to properly handle the JDO-Datanucleus-DBCP2 configuration using JDOHelper?

Comment: No idea what you mean "properly handle". Where are your JDO properties that define the PMF? Are you using the internal DataNucleus "dbcp2" provider or setting pooling on your own DataSource?

Comment: We use the properties from a .properties file like datanucleus.connectionPoolingType, datanucleus.connectionPool.minIdle, etc. Then, in the Java code we have JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(properties) - the properties is a java.util.Properties object which contains the ones from the file. We are using the internal DataNucleus dbcp2, which handles the object creation and DBCP integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems some weird DBCP2 thing that it should do itself but isn't for some reason. In the [DataNucleus DBCP2 connector code](https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-rdbms/blob/master/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/store/rdbms/connectionpool/DBCP2ConnectionPoolFactory.java#L74) they have

```
connectionPool = new org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool(poolableCF);
```

I personally would expect this to be enough for DBCP2 to know that the pool DBCP2 library returns is linked to the `poolableCF` (i.e what was passed in), but it gives this log message if you just do that. If you add the following line

```
poolableCF.setPool(connectionPool);
```

immediately after in their code you don't get that log message. Maybe you'd like to contribute it to the DataNucleus project?

Comment: Indeed, this was my first thought also when I saw the code (the integration is not fully finished). Beside of this, when the DBCP2 pool is created, they didn't sent the new properties (as logAbandoned). I have tried to use datanucleus.connectionPool.driverProps, but I'm not sure 100% that it worked. Thanks for the answer Neil!

Comment: so if you think you can improve their implementation then contribute it to that project; that is how open source should work